# Google Maps and accessbillity

Tags: google-maps, accessibility

I am a bit stuck in relation to make my pages accessible when embedding a Google Maps iframe.

When adding `role="application" aria-label="Location of the listing on a map" tabindex="0"` I get the error related to missing alt tags on the Google map images.

Adding `aria-hidden="true"` Wave and Axe tool complaint about interactable elements inside the iframe.

Which is the best solution?

Comment: It seems that accessibility for Google Maps images is not yet supported. Here's a public [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/69541792) related to your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Maps is still a pretty inaccessible product. Google has tried to make some strides with accessibility, but all-in-all, it's still not great.

An `iframe` of a Google map will be even more inaccessible. You could add a `title` or `aria-label` or `aria-labelledby` attributes, but these things can only describe the purpose and intent of the frame. Visitors will still have a tough time interacting with the embedded map. I would not recommend adding any ARIA roles to the iframe.

Linking directly to the Google Maps page via a hyperlink provides a little better experience (but still not great). Users will be able to tab through the map and directions better than they could in the iframe. Turn-by-turn directions on Google Maps offer a more accessible experience than maps showing locations.

You don't have to remove the `iframe` from the page if you don't want to, as it still has value to sighted visitors. You may, however, want to consider:

- adding a link to open the map directly on the Google Maps website
- offering a link to a separate page of text-based directions coming from each major highway (if directions are the goal of your map) - you could also use [hidden text](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/#offscreen) that would make this invisible to sighted visitors

You also have options for how to handle the `iframe` itself. You can either:

- add `aria-hidden` to the `iframe`, thereby removing it from the flow for users of assistive technology, but visible for sighted users, instead offering the alternative solutions presented above
- leave the `iframe` in the page flow (i.e. not hidden for anyone) add an accessible name (using `title`, `aria-label` or `aria-labelledby`) to the `iframe` so that visitors using assistive technology can understand the purpose, but probably not interact with it
- remove the `iframe` altogether and let all visitors use the link on the Google Maps website

Things like AXE and WAVE are a good starting point, but don't worry too much about getting a "perfect score" from them. The goal is to make pages that are as useful as possible for real people.

Comment: Thanks for that reflection... will look into this further. I will need to be ADA compliant which means WCAG 2.0 level AA minimum. Going to see how I can threat the iframe in this case. For visual point of view, I will leave it, like you mention even people with limited eye sight will profit from it.